# Grid Layout: create CSS so Elements keep position when adjacent element gets resized

Tags: css, layout, gallery, mouseover, grid-layout

I want to build a simple image gallery in grid layout, and I'm using something like this
[Zoom on hover](http://www.javascript-fx.com/navigation/imagezoom/general_help/help.html) to zoom hovered images.
But instead the table-style from the link, I'd rather use an UL (unsorted list). Well maybe table is also ok, you tell me :)

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li class="thumb"><a href="images/001.jpg" style="position:relative; left:2px; top:1px">
        <img class="" src="images/001thumb.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver="JSFX.zoomIn(this)" onMouseOut="JSFX.zoomOut(this)">
    </a></li>
    <li class="thumb"><a href="images/002.jpg" style="position:relative; left:3px; top:0px">
        <img class="" src="images/002thumb.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver="JSFX.zoomIn(this)" onMouseOut="JSFX.zoomOut(this)"> 
    </a></li>
    <li class="thumb"><a href="images/003.jpg" style="position:relative; left:1px; top:1px">
        <img class="" src="images/003thumb.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver="JSFX.zoomIn(this)" onMouseOut="JSFX.zoomOut(this)"> 
    </a></li>
    <li class="thumb"><a href="images/004.jpg" style="position:relative; left:0px; top:0px">
        <img class="" src="images/004thumb.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver="JSFX.zoomIn(this)" onMouseOut="JSFX.zoomOut(this)"> 
    </a></li>
    <li class="thumb"><a href="images/005.jpg" style="position:relative; left:2px; top:3px">
        <img class="" src="images/005thumb.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver="JSFX.zoomIn(this)" onMouseOut="JSFX.zoomOut(this)"> 
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is - as I'm not very good in this - I don't know how to adjust the CSS so that the elements around the hovered image won't get shifted..
I tried some things like display:block, but I guess I just don't know how would be an easy way to build this at all.. I don't need to show you my current ccs, as it's just a mixed up bunch of sh* o.O

I tried layouts like in the following examples, and the one did the shifting of beneath elements, the other did not "hover-zoom", as all elements were fixed in size:

[responsive-image-grids](http://alijafarian.com/responsive-image-grids-using-css/)

[image-grid-using-css-floats](http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/07/image-grid-using-css-floats_6950.html)

btw: in the anchor-tag, I'm using the style="..." (is inline-style html5-conform btw?) to individually shift the tiles, to create a bit of a random effect, but also not sure if I would put it there, in the li-tag, or img tag. I just don't wanna put it in the css for each image.
Finally it all should look like this:
[image]

Do you have some hints, or a helping hand for a very neat and easy css? I don't need nothing fancy, I will crop all my thumbnails by hand (well by photo-editor not scissors), and if it would be too complicated, I would also make the whole grid a fixed size, w/o resizing option. But preferable it should scale or rearrange on windowresize.

Comment: Use `transform:scale( value );`

Comment: @Paulie_D you mean instead of the jsfx-zoom script?  Is that compatible to ie8 and would also get rid of my main issue of the shift?

Comment: just found this, so maybe support is there, with an option for ie8 to use -ms-zoom: [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn6Ek/1/)**

It's just a matter of having a hover state where you can change the `width`+ `height` or you can use `transform: scale();`. I set the scaling elements to `position: absolute` just so you can make sure the `z-index` of the hovered element is always the highest.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        // many <li> elements
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

.wrapper {width: 300px;}

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
}
a {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}
a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    transform: scale(2,2);
    z-index: 100;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: yes this approx. what I need. In my own code, I currently dont get it that nice as in your example, but I'll try. Would css zoom be prefered over javascript, for peformance/loading time?

Comment: badAdviceGuy ;) - how would you put img-tags inside the a-tags and center them? I always have'em hanging in the left-upper edge..

Comment: You should be able to recreate this effect with `img` tags in your `a`tags. See this updated demo [http://jsfiddle.net/Gn6Ek/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn6Ek/2/). You'll need to give the images `width:100%` and be sure to give your `li` elements `position: relative`

Comment: hm thank you. but it will only center horizontally in my case. But as your fiddle looks very good, I think I will dig in my code where the error must be found. thx!

Comment: ah and can you say sth to the loading time JS vs CSS?

Comment: As far as I understand the loading time for this with pure CSS will be quicker. Less http requests, and it doesn't have to wait until the dom  is ready etc. However, not all browsers support `transition` and `:hover`, if you need to support older versions of IE you probably want to go with JS.