# Hover animation stops immediately when the mouse is no longer hovering over it?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I have an image that has a wobble animation that is activated when the mouse hovers over it and is supposed to last for about a second. If the mouse stays on the image, it works perfectly and goes for that length of time. However, if I move the mouse away from the image, it jerks back in place and doesn't finish the animation. How can I get it to continue the animation and then stop like it would if the mouse was still hovering over it?

HTML:

```
<img class="animated wobble" src="image/elephant.png"/>
```

CSS:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wobble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }

  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }

  45% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
    transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
    transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes wobble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }

  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }

  45% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
    transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
    transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.wobble:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: wobble;
  animation-name: wobble;
}
```

Comment: have you trought with **jquery** ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation --- It offers a javascript and a css solution (unconfirmed).

Comment: Also related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822249/css-transition-stops-abruptly-on-mouseout - essentially the same issue and it appears to have no solution using pure CSS.

Comment: I tried the first link and the code is a lot different. I don't know enough about JavaScript to add it to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/pedab/1/edit)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="animated" src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(".animated").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("wobble")  
}).hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("wobble");        
});
```

**CSS**

```
.wobble {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: wobble;
}

@keyframes wobble {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }

  15% {
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  30% {
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }

  45% {
    transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  60% {
    transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
  }

}
```